# Nuxtjs and Nginx Proxy Downloads File Without "http://"

Tags: nginx, server

I created a project with Laravel API and NuxtJS (SSR)

Deployed it on an AWS server running Ubuntu (18.04 LTS). My problem is that whenever I will go to the link "**example.com**" it will download a file but whenever I add a, for example, an **http://** or **https://** it works normally.

Here's my server block:

```
# Default

map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        "text/html"                     epoch;
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"      epoch;
        default                         off;
}

server {
    # listen [::]:80 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    # Logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

    location / {

        expires $expires;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version                  1.1;
        proxy_set_header                    upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header                    Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header                    Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass                  $http_upgrade;

        proxy_redirect                      off;

    }

    location ~ /\.{
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

to:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri
}
```